# How to find current location longitudes and latitude in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How to show current location point on alert (Geolocation in titanium ) in titatnium.I don't find any good tutorial for that . .can you please give some example.

I find some where this 
First, you will need to define why you want to use the geolocation. This message will be displayed to the user.
**Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Location will be used for app X";**
What is use of this line ? can we write anything here intead of this line Location will be used for app X

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using this simple code, you can print an alert with latitude and longitude variables:

```
if(Ti.Network.online){
        Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Receive User Location";
        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){

            if (!e.success || e.error)
            {
                alert('Could not find the device location');
                return;
            }
            var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = e.coords.latitude;

            alert("latitude: " + latitude + "longitude: " + longitude);

        });
    }else{
        alert("Internet connection is required to use localization features");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-getCurrentPosition